# Mongo-express from Docker not connecting to Mongo

Tags: docker

I know this question has been asked before and I've tried going through all the answers with no success.  To start off, I am new to Docker so please forgive me if something obvious was missed.
Whether in docker-compose or cmd line, I can't get mongo-express to connect to Mongo DB.
Below I'm only asking about the cmd line as I would think I need to at least get that working.

Env: Windows 10 Pro with WSL2 / Ubuntu 20.04 and Docker Desktop version 20.10

mongo cmd line:

```
docker run -d --name mongo-dev -p 27017:27017 -v ~/mongodata:/data/db \
-e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME='admin' -e MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE='auth' \
-e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD='pass' --hostname mongo-dev --network bridge mongo
```

I wait for it to fully start by checking logs:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-30T16:14:35.373+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
```

Then run mongo-express with the cmd line:

```
docker run -d --name me -p 8081:8081 -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME='admin' \
-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD='pass' -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER='mongo-dev' \
-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT=27017 --hostname me --network bridge mongo-express
```

mongo-express logs:

```
Wed Dec 30 16:44:02 UTC 2020 retrying to connect to mongo-dev:27017 (5/5)
/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 14: mongo-dev: Name does not resolve
/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 14: /dev/tcp/mongo-dev/27017: Invalid argument
...
Error [MongoError]: failed to connect to server [mongo-dev:27017] on first connect
```

In the few seconds that mongo-express is running, I tried:
`docker exec me ping mongo-dev` and get `"ping: bad address 'mongo-dev'"`
(`docker exec me ping me` does work)

Can anyone help?

I believe my question is less about mongo-express and more about why "mongo-dev" can't be resolved within the mongo-express container.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create a custom network of type **bridge** as mentioned in the official [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge). All the containers, attached to the custom network, are by default linked by **name** in a custom network. However, if you want to go with the option `--network bridge`, which is default, then you have to use the legacy `--link` flag to link the containers explicitly, as mentioned in the official documentation.

I am adding commands for the custom network option below:

```sh
docker network create mongo-net

docker run -d --name mongo-dev -p 27017:27017 -v ~/mongodata:/data/db \
-e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME='admin' -e MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE='auth' \
-e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD='pass' --hostname mongo-dev --network mongo-net mongo

docker run -d --name me -p 8081:8081 -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME='admin' \
-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD='pass' -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER='mongo-dev' \
-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT=27017 --hostname me --network mongo-net mongo-express
```

I have also verified that the mongo-express container, `me`, has connected successfully to the `mongo-dev` db container.

`docker logs me` has given the below output.

```
Waiting for mongo-dev:27017...
Welcome to mongo-express
------------------------


Mongo Express server listening at http://0.0.0.0:8081
Server is open to allow connections from anyone (0.0.0.0)
basicAuth credentials are "admin:pass", it is recommended you change this in your config.js!
Database connected
Admin Database connected
```

Have fun with Docker ;)

Comment: Thank you.  When I inspected the default bridge network (when both containers were running), I saw them both listed.  I thought that would mean they can talk to each other.

Comment: This answer just helped me. I had to change one thing to make it work though:
I had to take the single quotes off of ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER='mongo-dev' to get it to work. Worked using ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongo-dev

Answer (score 0):

OK, I had lot's of trouble about it too. Two afternoons or something. Try this, try that. And here is my solution:

Made network first:

```
sudo docker network create mongo-network-one
```

Mongo, with NO changing container name, environmental parameters copied from  hub.docker documentation:

```
sudo docker run -p 27017:27017 -d -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=example --name mongo --net mongo-network-one mongo:latest
```

Then mongo-express, NO name changed:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8081:8081 
-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=root  
-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=example  
-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL='mongo://root:example@mongo:27017'
-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongo 
-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN='true' 
--net mongo-network-one --name mongo-express mongo-express:latest
```

Connects database with mongo-express logs:

Waiting for mongo:27017...
No custom config.js found, loading config.default.js
Welcome to mongo-express 1.0.2

Mongo Express server listening at http://0.0.0.0:8081
Server is open to allow connections from anyone (0.0.0.0)
basicAuth credentials are "**admin:pass**", it is recommended
you change this in your config.js!

I'm still not sure where it went wrong, but this works. Obviously docker overrides our custom password and replaces it with default one. Therefore environmental inputs connected with custom password and custom admin are maybe not necessary. So, try this, it worked for me!
(go to localhost:8081 and enter default admin name and password)

PS:
If you want try to put admin and password into single quotes, but I think result will be the same!